# Task.WaitAll() - no parameters

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Using  `System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll()` I could see the available parameters I should be using with this method

Can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall.aspx) but when writing in visual studio, I was able to call the method with no parameters at all:

```
Task.WaitAll();
```

and it didn't show up as a syntax error in the IDE (for missing parameters), 
can you please explain why is this possible with this specific method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The full definition of this method is

```
public static void WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)
```

The word `params` indicates that the method accepts a variable number of arguments.  0 arguments is also explicitly allowed.

Needless to say the method has no effect when called this way.

Comment: @0A0D Why?  For many implementations of `params` no arguments is a sensible thing to use, for example `Console.WriteLine()`.  It's just not meaningful (and also not problematic) in this particular case.

Comment: @Servy: There are at least a few cases where in C# the compiler will warn you to ensure that's what you really intended. It's not an error and warnings can sometimes show unintended bugs.

Comment: @0A0D Yes, I know that, and when adding a compiler warning they take great pains to ensure that there is a very high probability that the code is a bug.  In this case, it's not a very high probability.  This is more like the exception than the rule.  Also note that the negative consequences of using this code are very, very small, again a point against adding a compiler warning.  Do you really want to see a compiler warning every time you write `Console.WriteLine()`?  I know I don't.

Comment: @Servy: Fair enough, but Console.WriteLine() actually writes a newline because it appends a new line to the end of the param passed in. Whereas Task.WaitAll() does nothing. It checks if params is > 0 and if it is, returns. To be complete, it really needs an explicit variable length param. Don't really see a need to call Task.WaitAll().

Comment: @0A0D And how does the compiler know the difference?  They're both just `params` calls that are given an empty collection.

Comment: @Servy: It doesn't now, but it could. Really, it's a stupid argument. I was just mentioning that it was a nice to have.

Comment: @0A0D So you want to special case `Task.WaitAll` as a method?  What would be the point?  What's the value gained?  You're not preventing any significant negative consequences, and you're not preventing minor negative consequences to a significant number of people.  Totally not worthwhile.  It will either have a negligible net value, if it's even positive at all.

Answer (score 3):

The method is overloaded. [One overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) is of the form:

```
public static void WaitAll(
    params Task[] tasks
)
```

The `params` parameter can take zero or more parameters.